QGIS model designer field name as variable in expression
I am trying to use Extract by Expression in Model Designer with the following:
@SearchField ilike concat('%', @SearchWord ,'%')
but it returns an empty layer.
If I specify the field name like so:
"terrang" ilike concat('%', @SearchWord ,'%')
it works correctly. This, is not how I want the model to work as it will be used on many different layers and on different fields.
In the example above the variables have been set with "Set Project Variables" but I have also tried simply using the "Field parameter Definition" directly but the result is the same.
This is, as far as I can see, the same problem as given here but that didn't get any suitable answer (Extract by attribute has the same problem and using "contains" cannot cope with upper and lower case variations).
Why will the @SearchField variable not give the correct result? Is the expression trying to match the the field name rather than the content? If so, how do I specify that the expression should use the content of the field rather than the field name?

OK, so writing the question got me thinking (should have done that earlier):
attribute(@SearchField) ilike concat('%', @SearchWord ,'%')
gives the correct result.
